# Salesforce CLI support CSV data import on Big Objects?

Tags: salesforce, sfdx, salesforce-cli, salesforce-sfdx

Does Salesforce CLI (SFDX CLI) support big objects.

How can we perform data import on big object from CSV file using SFDX CLI ...

I am trying to run "sf data upsert bulk" command to import the data from csv.
Following error is shown while executing above command.

"no create/update access for <abc__b> big objects salesforce"

Answer (score 0):

Can you send your command to further look into it?

Also, I guess No, the sf data upsert bulk command in Salesforce DX CLI is not ideally suited for importing data into big objects. While SFDX supports big objects overall, this specific command has limitations for big object data import due to two main reasons:

1. Designed for Standard Objects: The sf data upsert bulk command is primarily designed for bulk operations on standard Salesforce objects. It may not have the necessary optimizations for handling the large datasets typically associated with big objects.
2. Bulk API Constraints: Big objects have limitations on bulk operations due to their massive size. The standard Bulk API functionality used by sf data upsert bulk might not be efficient or reliable for handling large big object datasets.

Try the below -

**Bulk API using sfdx force:data:bulk:load**

The `sfdx force:data:bulk:load` command leverages the Salesforce Bulk API, specifically designed for efficient data import and export of large datasets, including big objects.  Here's the basic syntax:

> sfdx force:data:bulk:load -s <BigObject_Name> -f <data.csv> -i <Job_Id>

- Replace <BigObject_Name> with the actual name of your big object.
- Replace <data.csv> with the path to your CSV file containing the data.
- The -i <Job_Id> flag (optional) allows you to specify an existing job ID for resuming a previously started import process.